# ClientError: Unauthorized - Session does not match project host

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, authorization, sanity

Please help me out with this. I was trying to run `npm run build` but got [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9QTF.png) instead.
If you want anything, please comment!
I was expecting a green check!

Comment: Question is unclear. You need to show what is `build` command and what does it run. Looking at the console I can see that you are aprobably missing some auth keys/tokens (maybe they should be placed in env files?). Sorry, but no one will help you if you don't know what exactly needs to be fixed and on what question you want to receive an answer. You need to edit your question or probably it will be closed